# Looping in text file

Tags: excel, vba

I've came up with a bit of code that extracts certain values in a text file using VBA. I need it to loop as many times as the expression 'INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL' appear in the text file. Here's my code so far:

exemple of text file:

```
INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL  

Nom de l'individu ................. Louis Boutel  
Sexe .............................. Homme  
Numéro d'assurance sociale  ....... 323-423-123  
No employé ........................ 14023  
Date de naissance ................. 1969-03-22  
Date d'emploi ..................... 1998-09-28  

INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL  

Nom de l'individu ................. Morin laprise  
Sexe .............................. Homme  
Numéro d'assurance sociale  ....... 123-012-012  
No employé ........................ 14023  
Date de naissance ................. 1959-06-14 
Date d'emploi ..................... 1996-10-22
```

I Expected to have in Excel:

```
INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL  
Date d'emploi 1998-09-28  
INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL  
Date d'emploi 1996-10-22
```

Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, DDC As Integer, i As Integer, sArray(4) As String

myFile = "C:\Users\mark\Desktop\C0010DET.txt"
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
     text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1


    i = 1

    Dim vItm As Variant
    Dim aStrings(1 To 2) As String

    aStrings(1) = "INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL": aStrings(2) = "INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL"

    For Each vItm In aStrings
        DDC = InStr(text, "Date d'emploi")
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Mid(text, DDC, 14)
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Mid(text, DDC + 36, 10)
        Next vItm

End Sub
```

Do you know how I could run this sequence using a loop so I can retrieve all information needed?

Comment: What's working? What information? All we can see is you read in a text file omitting new lines. With this 1 lone line, you looped twice (due to aStrings) and extracting some string to cells that doesn't change row on next item. Then some maths (v and j) to extract text to rows that got overwritten later on... totally confused me what you are trying to do.

Comment: Without seeing what your text file looks like it's difficult to make any guesses here.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub test()

    Const S_HDR As String = "INFORMATION DE BASE ET DONNÉES DE CALCUL"
    Const S_DT As String = "Date d'emploi"

    Dim myFile As String, textline As String
    Dim c As Range

    myFile = "C:\Users\mark\Desktop\C0010DET.txt"

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, textline
        textline = Trim(textline)

        If textline Like S_DT & "*" Then
            c.Value = S_HDR
            c.Offset(1, 0).Value = S_DT
            c.Offset(1, 1).Value = Right(textline, 10)
            Set c = c.Offset(2, 0)
        End If

    Loop
    Close #1

End Sub
```